# How to create relationships for all the existing nodes with cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have created **Employees** and **Companies** nodes in the Neo4j database. Employees  collection has foreign key [CompanyID] which is a primary key in Companies collection. Now I want to create a relationship **[: WORKS_FOR ]** for all the nodes. Is there a way to do this?

I tried something similar to this, but it didn't work:

MATCH (e:Employee),(c:Company)

WHERE e.companyId = c.id

CREATE (e)-[:WORKS_FOR]->(c);

Answer (score 2):

For some reason the e.companyId is stored as a string, so converting c.id to string and comparing the ids worked for me.

MATCH (e:Employee),(c:Company)

WHERE e.companyId = **toString(c.id)**

CREATE (e)-[:WORKS_FOR]->(c);